# View transition animation having a snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

I have several swipe and pan gestures to navigate through some views. When I pan the view, a new ViewController will be instantiated and placed at the edge of the window. Along my pan, the view will come into view on top of the current view. If the pan has passed halfway, the new view will automatically finish and replaces the current view and on completion removing the old view.

```
var newViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        if let newView = NewViewController {
            addChildViewController(newView)
            newView.view.frame.origin.x = view.bounds.width }
            view.addSubview(newView.view)
            newView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        }
    }
}

var currentViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet(oldView) {
        oldViewController = oldView
        newViewController = nil
    }
}

var oldViewController: UIViewController!

func removeViewController() {
    if let oldView = oldViewController {
        oldView.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        oldView.view.removeFromSuperview()
        oldView.removeFromParentViewController()

        oldViewController = nil
    }
}

newViewController = NewVIewController()
currentViewController = newViewController

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.currentViewController.view.frame.origin.x = 0 }) { _ in
        self.removeViewController()
}
```

In the completion of the animation, the old view will be taken care of. But to make my app to be more responsive, I'd like to call `removeViewController` right away and still keeping a "snapshot" of the oldView so the transition will still look the same.

Should I use some other method for transitioning the views?

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to follow the pan gesture once the swipe event has been fired. Instead consider using uiscreenedgegesturerecognizer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is not how you do an interactive view controller transition. You need to trigger an actual view controller transition (e.g. call `presentViewController`) and supply a UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning object.

Comment: Is it also possible to do it without changing ViewControllers? The reason I'm asking is, because I'm working with a containerViewController and those views are handled without changing it's controller.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case you do have to do it all manually; the built-in transition animation customization feature is only for navigation controller, tab bar controller, and presented controller.

Comment: So what is the difficulty about the snapshot?

Comment: I've read about it but was unsure if that's the way it should be done (with a snapshot). Thought there might be a better way or method in achieving this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it" or "should be done". I don't understand the issue you are having. But the purpose of a snapshot is, in part, to replace a (heavyweight or immovable) view with a (lightweight and movable) snapshot. If you want to use a snapshot, use one! Animation is just the sort of situation they are made for.